# ¿Cómo obtener el id de una lista dentro de otra lista?

Tags: python, lista, csv

**Cundo trabajo con archivos CSV en python quiero traer el dato de id de una lista que esta dentro de otra lista o numero de elemento de esa lista.**

**Lo que hace este programa es: pide entrada para buscar una concidencia en el csv, itera en la lista csv, Si en la fila 1 hay un valor igual a la entrada, imprime los valores de la lista que coincide.**

```py
    import csv
    number = input('Ingresa número a buscar\n')
    with open('Uno.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        csvr = list(reader)

    for row in csvr:
        if number in row[1]:
            print(row)
```

**esto imprime la lista similar a la siguiente**
**['2098', '6699182318'] pero se requiere saber el numero del elemento que es la lista que se encuentra en el csv**

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta a castellano.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más rápida y simple de obtener el índice o posición de un elemento de una lista mientras la iteras es con enumerate. Con esta función es como si iterases dos listas a la vez, una primera compuesta de números de 0 al n-1, y la otra es la lista original.

```
import csv
    number = input('Ingresa número a buscar\n')
    with open('Uno.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        csvr = list(reader)

    for index, row in enumerate(csvr):
        if number in row[1]:
            print('Encontrado el numero en la fila', index, 'del fichero')
            print(row)
```